# How to play next iTunes' song in Automator

Tags: macos, automator

I'm on macOS High Sierra 10.13.3
and Automator version 2.8

I'm making my Automator script with setting specific iTunes playlist and to run it at specific time. But it always playing the same track. Is there a way to make Automator play next song?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it with AppleScript:

Example code:

```
tell application "iTunes"

    repeat (random number from 2 to 8) times
        next track
    end repeat

end tell
```